# Getting Deprecated methods and warning in RazorPay-Cordova Plugin

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic4, razorpay

I am trying to build ios application using ionic framework. I am using razorypay (payment gateway) to accept payments.

Razorpay is correctly working with browser but when i am trying to build it with `ionic cordova build ios`

Works Correctly on browser.

Task done

1. ionic cordova platform add ios
2. ionic cordova build ios(getting warning about deprecated methods)
3. Added import directive of RazorPay in Main.m file.
4. Tested on browser.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

declare var RazorpayCheckout: any;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-razorpay',
  templateUrl: './razorpay.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./razorpay.page.scss'],
})
export class RazorpayPage {
  amount: number;
  currency = 'INR';
  razorKey = 'somekeyoverhere';
  paymentAmount = this.amount;
  constructor(public router: Router) { }

  payWithRazor() {
    const options = {
      description: 'Credits towards consultation',
      currency: this.currency, // your 3 letter currency code
      key: this.razorKey, // your Key Id from Razorpay dashboard
      amount: this.paymentAmount, // Payment amount in smallest denomiation e.g. cents for USD
      name: 'Techmave Solutions',
      prefill: {
        email: 'yash@techmavesolution.com',
        contact: '9561555479',
        name: 'Enappd'
      },
      theme: {
        color: '#F37254'
      },
      modal: {
        ondismiss: () => {
          alert('dismissed');
          this.goToResponseError();
        }
      }
    };

    const successCallback = paymentId => {
      this.goToResponseSuccess(paymentId);
    };

    const cancelCallback = error => {
      // alert(error.description + ' (Error ' + error.code + ')');
     // this.goToResponseError(error.code);
    };

    RazorpayCheckout.open(options, successCallback, cancelCallback);
  }

    goToResponseSuccess(paymentId) {
      this.router.navigate(['/response', paymentId]);
    }

    goToResponseError() {
      this.router.navigate(['/response']);
    }
}
```

I am getting warnings as shown below.

```
/Users/yashtalegaonkar/Desktop/ionic-code/myapp/platforms/ios/MyApp/Plugins/com.razorpay.cordova/Razorpay/Main.m:28:1: warning: 

      implementing deprecated method [-Wdeprecated-implementations]
- (void)onPaymentError:(int)code
^

In module '
Razorpay
' imported from 
/Users/yashtalegaonkar/Desktop/ionic-code/myapp/platforms/ios/MyApp/Plugins/com.razorpay.cordova/Razorpay/Main.h
:
2
:

MyApp/Plugins/com.razorpay.cordova/Razorpay.framework/Headers/Razorpay-Swift.h
:
275
:
1
:
 note: method


'onPaymentError:description:andData:'

declared

here

- (void)onPaymentError:(int32_t)code description:(NSString * _Nonnull)str andData:(NSDictionary * _Nullable)response SW...


^


/Users/yashtalegaonkar/Desktop/ionic-code/myapp/platforms/ios/MyApp/Plugins/com.razorpay.cordova/Razorpay/Main.m:10:17: warning: 

class 'Main' does not conform to protocol 'ExternalWalletSelectionProtocol' [-Wprotocol]
@implementation Main


                ^


/Users/yashtalegaonkar/Desktop/ionic-code/myapp/platforms/ios/MyApp/Plugins/com.razorpay.cordova/Razorpay/Main.m:10:17: note: 
      add stubs for missing protocol requirements
@implementation Main
                ^

2 warnings generated.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The warnings are because of deprecated code inside cordova and razorpay hence it outputs a warning.**

***Warnings wont be a problem to run the app or deploy it*** as I have researched over it. Cordova has multiple deprecated methods so it helps us to run on lower version of iOS (9^).

Steps I followed

> Enable Bitecode 
>   Embed Libraries of Cordova 
>   Embed Razorpay Framework